# Create own grouping in Qlik

Tags: qlikview

I have a dimension

```
Group:
A
B
C
D
```

And Data:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | Amount | Group |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |     10 | A     |
|  1 |     20 | C     |
|  2 |     30 | A     |
|  3 |     40 | A     |
|  3 |     50 | B     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

In my data, it will not have group `D` exists, the logic will be if exists in group `A`, but didn't exists in group `B or C`, then it will classify to group `D`

in above example, it should have a "hidden" data as

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | Amount | Group |
+----+--------+-------+
|  2 |     10 | D     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

I know that I can create that in `Load` script, but my data are stored as month by month, which means it can create triple or more dummy data.

*Question*
So is it possible to use the expression to create grouping?

In my bar chart, I have a dimension:

```
=IF(Group = 'A', null(), Group)
```

For measure, my idea it may be

```
Group D:
sum({$<Group = 'A'>} Amount) - sum({$<Group = - 'A', ID = P({$<Group = 'A'>} ID)>} Amount)
Other Group:
sum({$<Group = - 'A', $<ID = P({$<Group = 'A'>} ID)>} Amount)
```

result table:

```
+-------+--------+
| Group | Amount |
+-------+--------+
| B     |     50 |
| C     |     20 |
| D     |     30 |
+-------+--------+
```

underlying table:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | Amount | Group |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |     20 | C     |
|  2 |     30 | D     |
|  3 |     50 | B     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to display this? ID =2 in your example should then not be group A but group D? Since it did not exist in B nor D?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the example, `ID = 2` should be in `Group D` but not `ID = 1`.

Comment: I honestly do not see how you will be able to do this in an expression while keeping the response time low. This is best done in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem,

Your examples are a bit incorrect, as the ID 2 has an amount of 30 instead of 10 in your example:

What I would do is something in these lines.

IN Script:

```
DATA:
LOAD * INLINE [
    ID, Amount, Group 
    1, 10, A     
    1, 20, C     
    2, 30, A     
    3, 40, A     
    3, 50, B     
];
Left Join
LOAD ID, Concat(Group,',') as GroupLink Resident DATA Group By ID;
```

Then in your dimensions:

```
=If(WildMatch(GroupLink,'A') AND NOT (WildMatch(GroupLink,'B') OR WildMatch(GroupLink,'C')), 
'D', Group)
```

Then in your expression:

```
=Sum(Amount)
```

Will yield the following:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add a calculated dimension in your chart with aggr function

Comment: Any example? Or more detail?

Comment: You cannot use aggregates in dimensions, and even if you could this is bad practice.